# Check existence of element in Result of AJAX Request

Tags: jquery, ajax

The code below always returns `$('.ErrorMessage', result).length` as 0.  I don't understand why though.  Ideas?

### AJAX Request

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: action,
                dataType: "html",
                data: serializedForm,
                success: function (result) {
                    if ($('.ErrorMessage', result).length > 0) {
                        $('#editSurveyModal').append(result);
                    }
                    else {
                       alert('fail');
                    }
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    alert('save fail');
                }
            });
```

### 'result' Returns.. (verified with an alert)

```
<div id="ErrorMessage" class="ErrorMessage">
    <div>
        Please correct the following errors before saving.
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: left">
        <ul>
           <li>Test</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

### What Im Trying to Do

I'm trying to see if the result is the above error partial view by checking for the ErrorMessage class somewhere in the result.

Comment: what is inside the `result` variable?

Comment: you always get a string response from an AJAX call, so "result" is string, not an actual DOM element. Take a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dealt with this exact same problem myself once.

You can't `.find()` it, because the element you're trying to find is at the root level of the collection.
*(Note that `$(selector, result);` is a shorthand syntax for `$(result).find(selector);`)*

However, `.filter('.ErrorMessage')` will match it, just fine.

(Incidentally, you'll run into the same problem when you pass a whole HTML document into the jQuery() function - then the `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` elements get stripped away.)

What you should do (to catch most/all edge-cases) is the following:

```
if ( $( '.ErrorMessage', $('<div/>').html( result ) ).length > 0 )
...
```

...and Bob's your uncle. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery to instantiate DOM elements from result first (adding them to a container), and then check:

```
$('.ErrorMessage', $("<div/>").html(result)).length
```

Comment: Not true. It doesn't matter that `result` is a string. His problem is unrelated to that fact. (Try this in your nearest Javscript console: `jQuery('p', '<div><p>tt</p></div>').length == 1`. jQuery is clever ;-)  See my answer below for solution.

Comment: @Mar: You are right, thanks, I updated my answer and +1'd yours

Answer (score 1):

You could deal with the result variable directly (as a string), and just use a regular expression to find the string "ErrorMessage" within it:

```
result.match('/ErrorMessage/')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your return is valid xml, so you can use 'xml' as dataType and get a document(instead of a string if you use 'html')